# How to check if an element value is null using xsl:if

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to implement an xsl in which a node from an xml be selected only if that element exists and have some value:

I did some research and this expression i found can be used in the test condition:

```
<xsl:if test="/rootNode/node1" >

 // whatever one wants to do   

</xsl:if>
```

Will it test for the existence of --> /rootNode/node1 only or check the contents of node1 as well? How does we check the contents of node1 in this expression that it should not be null.

Comment: What do you mean by "null"? There is no such thing in XML. Do you mean an element that is present but has no content?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following transformation should help you to handle all cases.

If the content of `node1` is text, you can use `text()` to detect it. If the content is any element, you can use `*` to detect it. To check if it is empty, you can add the condition `not(node())`. If you want to do things if `node1` itself is not present, add a `not(node1)` condition to the root node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/rootNode/node1/text()">
has text
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/rootNode/node1/*">
has elements
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/rootNode/node1[not(node())]">
is empty
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/rootNode[not(node1)]">
no node1
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can apply the same in `xsl:if` nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/rootNode">
        <xsl:if test="node1/text()">
        has text
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="node1/*">
        has elements
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="node1[not(node())]">
        is empty
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(node1)">
        no node1
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, however how do we specify it in <xsl:if test=" " > </xsl:if>; i don't want to create a <template> rule.

Comment: May be like this: <xsl:if test="/rootNode/node1/text()" >

 // whatever one wants to do   

</xsl:if>

Answer (score 1):

> Will it test for the existence of --> /rootNode/node1 only or check the contents of node1 as well?

It is an existence test.

> How does we check the contents of node1 in this expression that it should not be null.

It can't be null if the element is present. It can however be *empty.* In the case of an element, that would mean it has no children.